# Why is Heroku PostgreSQL row count much higher than sum of model instances from my Django app?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

My Heroku PostgreSQL utilization is showing 32k rows and 20 tables, when I only have 9 different model types in my Django app, and the highest count on any of these model types is <2000.

By I figure by this I should have 18,000 items max (and realistically much less because some of these models only have <100 items.

Am I misunderstanding how Django models relate to PostgreSQL row counts? Are there other items being stored in the DB that I am not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: You can connect to your database and see.
by default you have sessions, migrations, users and other different Django core tables depending on your configuration

Comment: hi @iklinac thanks so much, that's helpful to know

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question: can you please explain why? I did a search on the site and couldn't find anything that I considered a duplicate (please share link if you find one). Since Heroku charges above 10k DB rows I think it would be valuable to understand where these rows are being used besides Django model instances. Thank you.

Comment: @CaseyL plus in case you didn't account for these if you have any many to many fields those also have their own tables (Django makes a model implicitly if you don't specify one here), and by the fact that they connect instances of two models together these normally would have lot's of entries.